# How can I Add Days to a date property in Cypher?

Tags: date, neo4j, cypher, days

I have been working on a readmission issue using a clinical graph dataset. Let's say a patient is being readmitted within 30 days. So, this means I need add 30 days to the first date (visit date) for the second visit date.

Here is the Cypher query:

```
MATCH(p:Person)-[r:PATIENT_HAS]->(e:Encounter)  
WITH p,e 
MATCH (p)-[r:PATIENT_HAS]-(e2:Encounter) WHERE e2.ADMIT_DATE < (e.ADMIT_DATE + 30)
```

This query won't work because the date property is in YYYYMMDD format. For example, if it is 20151225, it will give 20151255. But I need to get it as 20160124 after adding 30 days. Is there any other way to use a different format than YYYYMMDD. I know that there is string format as YYYY-MM-DD, but what is the way to use this format for adding days?

How can accomplish this?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you considered using the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_time_support), which has support for dates and times?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to deal with dates in Neo4j in my opinion is to have them saved as UNIX epoch time in miliseconds or seconds. We have a great plugin in Neo4j called [apoc procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) that allows you to use awesome procedures. In your specific case I would utilize `apoc.date.*`procedures and parse your date format to epoch time in seconds.

```
MATCH (e:Encounter)
WITH e,apoc.date.parse(e.ADMIT_DATE,"s","YYYYMMDD") as unix
set e.unix = unix
```

So now your query would look like :

```
MATCH(p:Person)-[r:PATIENT_HAS]->(e:Encounter)   
MATCH (p)-[r:PATIENT_HAS]-(e2:Encounter) 
WHERE e2.unix < e.unix + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Ofcourse you can simplify this query and make it shorter:

```
MATCH  (e2:Encounter)-[r:PATIENT_HAS]-(p:Person)-[r:PATIENT_HAS]->(e:Encounter)  
WHERE e2.unix < e.unix + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: Seconded on using APOC procedures. And to make things easier, we have some new functions coming down the pipeline shortly for adding time using differing time units, so you could take a time in s (or ms, if you prefer) and add on 30 days worth of time without having to do the multiplication yourself. Something like `return apoc.date.add(e.unix, 's', 30, 'd') as thirtyDaysLaterInSeconds`

Comment: [`apoc.date.add()`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_adding_subtracting_time_unit_values_to_timestamps) is now available in APOC Procedures. Give it a try when you're able!

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a Duration, and add it directly to a date.
Here is an example in Cypher:

```
RETURN Date() + Duration({days: 30})
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/duration/

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using Neo4j 4.0.3 and the following works:

```
RETURN REPLACE(toString(date('20151225') + duration('P30D')),'-','')
// "20160124"
```

Answer (score 0):

We found out a temporary solution: We are setting a specific date in the past (1/1/2009 in our case), and are getting the difference between the first visit (e.ADMIT_DATE-1/1/2009) and the second visit (e2.ADMIT_DATE-1/1/2009) as days. Then we are able to get the difference between the first and second visits (e2.DAYS-e.DAYS) to figure out 30 days for the readmission criteria.

I had checked out the apoc procedures plugin and it seemed a bit complicated. But I can definitely retry it. Many thanks for your great responses folks.

Comment: Be careful, if those are the exact expressions you're using. `-1/1/2009` will be interpreted as subtracting 1 divided by 1 divided by 2009 (as integers, since none of the operands is floating point).